# How to effectively capture nested data?

Tags: tables, input, nested-tables

We need to capture data in the following structure(A json payload is the easiest way to represent the structure I know of):

```
{
  "A": [{
    "B1": "foo",
    "B2": 1,
    "B3": [{
      "C1": "bar",
      "C2": 2,
      "C3": [{
        "D1": "baz"
      }] 
    }]
  }]
}
```

The user has to capture this information in a form/forms/table. As you can see `A` is a collection of data, so is `B3` and `C3`. Basically it's nested collections of data.

Something to note is that the structure represents a single domain entity, i.e. `D1` doesn't make sense outside the context of the `C` items and so on.

We initially thought the easiest way split up the capturing process without loosing context would be to have an `A` page that has a table of `B` items and a button that allows you to add a `B` item. Upon clicking the `Add new B item` button you are taken to a page to capture `B1`, `B2` and a table for `B3` that contains `C` items also with a `Add new C item` button and so on... While maintaining context with a breadcrumb. So if the user is on the deepest page and capturing `D1` the breadcrumb would display `A/foo/bar`

The primary users of the system raised concern that there needs to many `A` items captured. And being moved from screen to screen would be frustrating. Their suggestion is that the data be captured in a table. e.g.

[image: Table Capture]

Our issue with this is that there is so much duplicated data being typed in over and over again. And another issue is the possibility that the user could make a typo, creating 2 instances when only one was intended i.e. `foo` and `fo0`

I guess my question is, is there a nice way to allow users to capture large amounts of nested data at once?

Answer (score 1):

Need to be careful to make sure that the user understands that there is a parent-child relationship here, that data from A dictates B and B dictates C. The table does not communicate that effectively.

A tree/map UI of some kind would allow the user to not lose the context of the parent values whilst capturing the child items...
Maybe allowing for a typeahead of some kind if the values are non-numeric, in order to use linking, instead of duplication. 
If the values in question are numeric, allow some kind of drop down to link to previously entered values and a numeric input field to add new values.
This also enables you to graphically represent the decisions/inputs made by the user in a tree/map, allowing the user to easily spot any mistakes.

[image: Value creation]

[image: TreeStructure]

This is like building a multi-level menu traversal, just easier to see all relations at once.

EDIT: You could also think of it as a multi-leaf tree/multiply linked list/map.

If there are multiple variants of A, so A1, A2 etc.. Then a matrix UI structure makes more sense.